# append new data at the end of json in php

Tags: php, json

I am trying to append new data at the end of predefined JSON.
i want to append new data as an element of existing json. i mean data is appended as new element of json.

```
$jsonData = array();
if (!empty($json_mainQuot)) {
  $jsonData['mainQuot'] = $json_mainQuot;
}
if (!empty($json_quotation_hotel)) {
  $jsonData['quotation_hotel'] = $json_quotation_hotel;
}
$tempArray[] = json_decode($state_current_arr[0]['user_date']);
array_push($tempArray, $jsonData);
$jsonData_merged = json_encode($tempArray);
```

it look like this

```
  [{
    "id": "77",
    "agent_id": "30524",
    "raised_by": "C",
    "from_date": "2016-11-09",
    "to_date": "2016-11-10",
    "num_of_days": "1",
    "num_of_country": "1",
    "LeadConsultant": {
        "user_id": "3045",
        "lead_id": "77"
    },
    "LeadDestination": [{
        "from_date": "2016-11-09",
        "to_date": "2016-11-10",
        "country_id": "IN",
        "city_id": "67457",
        "notes": "",
        "is_hotel": "1",
        "is_sight": "1",
        "is_transfer": "1",
        "lead_id": "77"
    }]
}, {
    "mainQuot": {
        "supplier_markup": "0",
        "lead_destination_id": "168",
        "user_id": "1",
        "quot_via": 0
    },
    "quotation_hotel": {
        "lead_quot_id": "36",
        "hotel_id": "578917",
        "giata_id": "531264",
        "ratings": "3",
        "address": "Opposite ST Stand,Alibag 402201",
        "notes": "testing"
    }
}]
```

but i want like this

```
    [{
    "id": "77",
    "agent_id": "30524",
    "raised_by": "C",
    "from_date": "2016-11-09",
    "to_date": "2016-11-10",
    "LeadConsultant": {
        "user_id": "3045",
        "lead_id": "77"
    },
    "mainQuot": {
        "supplier_markup": "0",
        "lead_destination_id": "168",
        "user_id": "1",
        "quot_via": 0
    },
    "quotation_hotel": {
        "lead_quot_id": "36",
        "hotel_id": "578917",
        "giata_id": "531264",
        "ratings": "3",
        "address": "Opposite ST Stand,Alibag 402201",
        "notes": "testing"
    },
    "LeadDestination": [{
        "from_date": "2016-11-09",
        "to_date": "2016-11-10",
        "country_id": "IN",
        "city_id": "67457",
        "notes": "",
        "is_hotel": "1",
        "is_sight": "1",
        "is_transfer": "1",
        "lead_id": "77"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: if you check what you want with a json validator, you will see that what you want is not a valid json.

Comment: actually, what you get is not a valid json either

Comment: now see it is valid json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need array_merge instead of array_push:

```
<?php

$state_current_arr = '{ "id": "77", "agent_id": "30524", "raised_by": "C", "from_date": "2016-11-09", "to_date": "2016-11-10", "LeadConsultant": { "user_id": "3045", "lead_id": "77" }, "LeadDestination": [ { "from_date": "2016-11-09", "to_date": "2016-11-10", "country_id": "IN", "city_id": "67457", "notes": ""}]}';

$jsonData = array();

    $jsonData['mainQuot'] = 'test';
    $jsonData['quotation_hotel'] = 'test';

$tempArray = json_decode($state_current_arr,true);
$tempArray = array_merge($tempArray, $jsonData);
$jsonData_merged = json_encode($tempArray);

echo $jsonData_merged;
```